# Won't start httpd after upgrading to httpd2.4 : Can't load modules

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I was required to update php5.3 to php5.5, which also resulted in upgrading httpd2.2 to httpd2.4. Now after i upgraded my httpd isn't starting, throwing error

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_authn_default.so
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_authz_default.so
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ldap.so
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_disk_cache.so
```

I commented the lines from httpd.conf which resulted to these

```
Starting httpd: AH00534: httpd: Configuration error: No MPM loaded.
```

I when to '00-mpm.conf' inside conf.modules.d and comment every mpm module but that didn't work. Also I did look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html but couldn't figure out what changes are to be done.

Can any one suggest me a link to load this modules. Since no package is there I cannot install modules using `yum install mod_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Apache httpd has 3 choices for MPM, and you have to select one.
You should not comment out all lines in 00-mpm.conf.

mpm_prefork is recommended if you use mod_php .

For example in your 00-mpm.conf,

```
 LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
```